# Text Align Property is not working for Span Tag

Tags: html, css, alignment

There is section inside which i have defined `text-align` as `left` for a line but its not taking effect for some reason

```
<section id="topic1">
This is a centered Heading for Topic 1<br>
<span class="text">This is a left aligned line</span>
</section>
```

```
section {
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

**I tried `display: block` for text `span` tag in above code and text got aligned to left but i am looking for a alternative way to do this**

---

**Reason for finding alternative way** - Even tho block display is aligning text to left , keeping display as block for all the span tags within my webpage increases the  space between each span tag for some reason

Practical example below

```
<span class="text">This is line 1</span><br>
<span class="text">This is line 2</span>
```

```
.text {
  display: block;
}
```

If you check output of above code there would be space between line 1 and 2 because of display block .
I am okay with using `display : block` to make `text align` work for `span` tag

But then this unnecessary space created by block display bothers me

Isn't there any way to avoid that unnecessary space ( seen between line 1 and 2 ) created while using block display

Comment: `text-align` will not work in a span tag, as the tag is only as large as the text inside - since it's an `inline` element. What you have with `inline-block` won't work either, because again, the `inline-block` is only as large as the text inside.

Comment: @disinfor keeping its display as block alignes it but adds some unnecessary space.  Please check updated question

Comment: Use CSS to change the spacing. There's nothing stopping you from using `margin` and `padding` properties from getting the space you want. You can also change the `span` to `div` - which has native `block` display. Edit your question to add multiple `spans` you may have.

Comment: @disinfor sorry for earlier confusion. I have updated my question again.  To me it now seems perfect.  Please read till end

Comment: `Isn't there any way to avoid that unnecessary ( seen between line 1 and 2 ) space created while using block display ` Yes. Use the `margin` property with a negative value if you need to. Also, don't add a `<br>` tag after a block element...not really useful in this case.

Comment: @disinfor thanks i used .text {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
} And its having space between lines like inline-block ( nothing extra ) and now i can align text too.

Comment: Added my answer at the same time you commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using `margin`. This will allow you to adjust the spacing between the blocks. Also, you can remove the `br` tags.

```css
section {
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 0;
  /* CHANGE THIS VALUE */
}
```

```html
<section id="topic1">
  This is a centered Heading for Topic 1
  <span class="text">This is line 1</span>
  <span class="text">This is line 2</span>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

An `inline-block`element  is only as wide as its contents, in your case NOT the full width of the container.

In their container inline-blocks are aligned according to the `text-align` setting of the parent element (= the container, in your case `#topic1`), thats why they are called INLINE-blocks.

So if you want it left-aligned, you have to change the alignment of `section` to `left`. And wrap your to be centered text in a heading element (like `<h1>...</h1>`, wich is a block element having 100% width by default) to which you apply `text-align: center`. And BTW, that would also improve the semantical quality of the HTML - headers should be wrapped in header tags.

About "unneccessary vertical space between lines": That the default `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of these elements - you can reduce those by defining them in the CSS for the according elements)

Answer (score 0):

You have a space after the period.

To select `class="text"`, use:

```
.text
```

not

```
. text
```

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo , i corrected it.  The reported question is still open

Answer (score 0):

**Try adding float: left instead of text-align:left. As span element or inline-block element take only fit width. float will help align the item with respect to parent.**

https://codepen.io/pratik-sangami/pen/dybKMVz

Comment: Thanks thats working well , it never really clicked to me that i can use float xd. Although i will remember it henceforth. Either a negative bottom margin to remove space of block display or inline block with float property

Comment: No offence, but try grid layout or flex layout. they are easier and modern frameworks use them, and i think is future. unless, some one compels you to use this layout.